# C# Reflection - Recursive method losing child properties

Tags: c#, reflection

just started experimenting with some reflection in C#. Pretty new to it and I just started with a simple recursive experiment. I have two classes:

```
public class Parent{

public ChildClass child = new ChildClass();
public string Name = "name";
private string Id = "id";

}

public class ChildClass{

public string ChildName = "someName";
private string ChildID = "someId";

}
```

I have those two, both containing two strings which I want to be able to edit.

Now I have this method:

```
private void EditStringsOfObject(object myObj){

    var fields = myObj.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public |
                                           BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);

    fields.Where(x => x.FieldType == typeof(string) && x.Getvalue(myObj) != null).ToList
    .ForEach(y => y.SetValue(myObj, SomeMethodManipulatingStrings(y.GetValue(myObj).ToString())));
```

I'm just gonna hop right in here and say that I've confirmed that this works as wanted. (Below is the continuation of EditStringsOfObject)

```
    var children = fields.Where(x => !x.FieldType.IsPrimitive &&
        !x.FieldType.Namespace.Contains("System") && !x.FieldType.IsArray).ToList
    .ForEach(EditStringsOfObject);
}
```

Might be a little messy, I apologise for that. 
Now it works perfectly when Parent is the parameter to EditStringsOfObject, however when it reaches the bottom and recursively calls EditStringsOfObjects with Parent.child, I lose the attributes ChildName and ChildID. Only fields I have left are some IntPtr and m_name (some reflectionfields or something). I don't know how I'm supposed to solve this without removing the recursive.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Reflection is not recommended unless you have any other way to do it.

Comment: You are calling `EditStringsOfObject` with the parameter `FieldInfo`. Presumably you wanted to pass the value of the field.

Comment: @activehigh I just wanted a really generic method for replacing certain characters of each objects' strings.

Comment: @Dirk Yeah, amazing what one can miss, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgot GetValue method when you call EditStringsOfObject for complex-type field collection

```
    private static void EditStringsOfObject(object myObj)
    {

        var fields = myObj.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public |
                                               BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);

        fields.Where(x => x.FieldType == typeof(string) && x.GetValue(myObj) != null)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(y => y.SetValue(myObj, SomeMethodManipulatingStrings(y.GetValue(myObj).ToString())));

        fields.Where(x => !x.FieldType.IsPrimitive && !x.FieldType.Namespace.Contains("System") && !x.FieldType.IsArray)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(x => EditStringsOfObject(x.GetValue(myObj)));            
    }
```

Comment: Ooooooh, that's what I was missing! Thanks alot! :D